# JS: How to solve this promise thing?

Tags: javascript, promise

What is the correct way to solve multi promises? Chain or .map them?

```
let promises = [];
// data is a binary zip file
JSZip.loadAsync(data).then((zip) => {
    for (let filename in zip.files) {
        zip.files[filename].async("blob")
        // ********** Problem! **********
        // because of the following .then, the promises.push is deferred
        // and so the next .then is run immediately
            .then((fileData) => {
                promises.push(this.file.writeFile(...));
            })
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(() => {
    ...
```

Comment: `return Promise.all(promises)`?

Comment: I've edit my code (just forgot to add it). It's not solving the problem.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: you're pushing to promsies asynchronously ... try `promises.push(zip.files .... etc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of knowing but suspecting `zip.files[filename].async("blob")` returns a promise resolving to fileData you should wait for `zip.files[filename].async("blob")` to resolve.

If zip.files is an array it would be more elegant to map `zip.files` to promises (see Mehari's answer), if it is an object then `map(Object.keys(zip.files)` would be better than `for in` (unless properties are in prototype of `zip.files`)

Does the following work?

```
JSZip.loadAsync(data)
.then((zip) => {
    let promises = [];
    for (let filename in zip.files) {
      promises.push(
        zip.files[filename].async("blob")
        // ********** Problem! **********
        // because of the following .then, the promises.push is deferred
        // and so the next .then is run immediately
        .then((fileData) => {
          this.file.writeFile(...)
        })
      )
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(() => {
```

Comment: Your answer would be more valuable to all if you explain the change you made and why you think it will work better than the code the OP had.  I think you have it right, but great answers don't make people figure out what you changed and why - they explain the logic so it's easier for all to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure about the asynchronous API's you are using but , the following snippet might give you some highlights

```
JSZip.loadAsync(data).then(zip => {
        const files = zip.files;
        const blobs = files.map(filename => {
            return files[filename].async("blob")
        });
        return Promise.all(blobs);
    })
    .then(fileData => {
        fileData.map(file => {
            // TODO... file.writeFile()
        });
    })
```